# is Encryption Class in codeigniter is secure and which cipher they used

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption

I am using `Encryption Class` in codeigniter. [Encryption Class Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/encryption.html). according to this documentation they used Mcrypt library.

According to PHP Manual [PHP Manual Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) at the below you see **User Contributed Notes**

> This extension rely in libmcrypt which is dead, unmaintained since
>   2007.
>
> Please don't rely on it, consider switching to well maintained
>   alternatives (openssl, crypt, password hashing functions, phpseclib,
>   password_compat...)

My question is

1. Is Encryption Class is secure or not?
2. If it's secure then how much i rely on this?
3. Finally which cipher they used to encryption or decryption? (AES, DES or Triple DES etc.)

I need your experience or Opinion about Encryption Class.

Thanks

Comment: CI has DEPRECATED Encryption class so you don't have to rely on it. [Encryption Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html)

Comment: @SaadSuri you solved my 1 problem. yes i am using encrypt class. `$this->load->library('encrypt');`

Comment: Bilal read this for passwords. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @Brad i know. we used Hash function for password (md5, SH1, SH2 etc). i am trying to encrypt some secret information

Comment: The hash function is not md5, sha1 or sha2. Do not use that for passwords. Use bcrypt.  Its better to use the Encryption Library, instead of the encrypt class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Encryption Class is secure or not?

Whether the *class* is secure is less relevant than what you are using it for. If you want to use if for password *encryption*, then I'd say no. Encrypting passwords is bad practice. You should *hash* them. For that I'd suggest to heed the note in the PHP Manual and use the [password hashing functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

> If it's secure then how much i rely on this?

How should *we* know how much *you* rely on this?

> Finally which cipher they used to encryption or decryption? (AES, DES or Triple DES etc.)

The docs you linked state it uses `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` as the default cipher with `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` for the default mode.

Comment: According to CI 3 docs they're using AES 128, and heavily rely on openssl, and mcrypt. [CI 3 userguide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) and yes Always hash password don't encrypt it

Comment: @SaadSuri I don't know which version of Code Igniter the OP uses. I assume since he linked the docs for CI2, they are stuck on that. But thanks for pointing it out.